# fatal: not a git repository: libbcc.git

Tags: android, git, repo, manjaro

I'm trying to compile TWRP for android 9 using manjaro
i used these commands:

```
mkdir twrp
cd twrp
repo init --depth=1 -u https://github.com/minimal-manifest-twrp/platform_manifest_twrp_omni.git -b twrp-9.0
repo sync
```

i get these errors:

```
platform/frameworks/compile/libbcc:
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/pc/twrp/.repo/projects/frameworks/compile/libbcc.git'
platform/frameworks/compile/libbcc: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/pc/twrp/.repo/projects/frameworks/compile/libbcc.git'
error: Cannot fetch platform/frameworks/compile/libbcc from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/compile/libbcc

fatal: not a git repository: '/home/pc/twrp/.repo/projects/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9.git'
error: Cannot fetch platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9 from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9
```

is there any solution?

i tried to change the python version from 3 to 2.7.18 but i get:
`repo sync File "/usr/local/bin/repo", line 51 def print(self, *args, **kwargs): ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`